# Different behaviour in bash when printing output from command compared to hardcoded string

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, tmux

I am trying to use tmux and simple bash scripts to get a very basic statusbar in my terminals - so the windows are very small (1 or 2 lines in height and potentially less than 10 characters in width).

The command that's causing a strange behaviour is:

```
echo "$(top -bn 1 | awk '/^%Cpu/{print $2}')%"
```

which is basically just supposed to print out something like `1.8%`.
In a normal sized terminal (with or without tmux) it works fine but when I shrink down the terminal, at some point it starts to cut off the number and only displays `%`. This might not seem too strange but when I put some text around this command, like

```
echo "ab$(top -bn 1 | awk '/^%Cpu/{print $2}'cd"
```

I get `abcd` as output when shrinking the terminal. So it's only affecting the part withing `$(...)` that gets cut away.

Also when I print two lines:

```
echo "$(top -bn 1 | awk '/^%Cpu/{print $2}'%"
echo "20.5%"
```

it will print `20.5%` fine, even break it up over several lines like

```
2
0
.
5
%
```

rather than just not printing parts of it. The first line however only shows `%` without any number.

Any idea what is causing this and how to get the numbers to show?

Comment: it sounds like the `top` command is checking the terminal size, even if its output is going to a pipe rather than the terminal.

Comment: `top` is designed for interactive use. It's generally not the right tool for what you're doing here. Might you consider switching to something built for the job, such as `vmstat`? Even better would be to have a program continually reading from a long-running copy of `vmstat` in the background and atomically updating a file on tmpfs (ie. `/dev/shm/cpu-usage`) with the CPU usage value as it changes; that way you avoid all the overhead of starting up a new process every time you want to write out a statusbar update, and needing to wait to allow it to collect data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `top` checks the terminal size and adjusts its output based on it, even when used in batch mode and output is being piped instead of going to the terminal. You can use the `-w` option to override this.

```
echo "$(top -w 50 -bn 1 | awk '/^%Cpu/{print $2}')%"
```

Comment: `-w` alone didn't work but with an argument like `-w 50` it did!
What I still don't understand is, when this was caused by `top`, then why did the output (dis-)appear when resizing the window even after running the command?
As in: small window, run `top -bn 1 | ... `, output is `%`, make window bigger, output is `1.8%`.
How come this changes even without re-running top?

Comment: I assumed you were re-running the command to update your statusbar.

Comment: Maybe tmux automatically re-runs it whenever the screen size changes.